# How do I show all of these HTML elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

So I have 4 elements which I want to display all in one line on my webpage:

```
  <input checked type="radio" name="TZ" id="local-time" ></input>
  <p id="inp-n1" class="disp">Local Time</p>
  <input type="radio" name="TZ" id="eastern-time" ></input>
  <p id="inp-n2" class="disp">Eastern Time</p>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option wrap it in a main div and set flex direction row.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input checked type="radio" name="TZ" id="local-time"></input>
  <p id="inp-n1" class="disp">Local Time</p>
  <input type="radio" name="TZ" id="eastern-time"></input>
  <p id="inp-n2" class="disp">Eastern Time</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use label instead of p, which is more preferred to use

```
<input checked type="radio" name="TZ" id="local-time" ></input>
<label for="local-time">Local Time</label>
<input type="radio" name="TZ" id="eastern-time" ></input>
<label for="eastern-time">Eastern Time</label>
```

Comment: This gives the added benefit of being able to click on the `label` to select the radio button. For completeness , the elements could be wrapped in a `fieldset` with an appropriate `legend`